# How to use POST in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, postman

I am using Postman extension in Google Chrome to get JSON data. When I pass in a url and use POST and give in the key Authorization and value of an api key I am getting JSON data. I want to do the same through angular so I can use the JSON data and display it on my view.

I am new in angular and don't know how to use the POST method.

Comment: `$http.post(url, data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
$http.post(url, postData,
{
    withCredentials: true,
    headers:{ 'Authorization': 'Basic' + token} //you add all your headers
}
).then(function(response){ 
   // here you treat your response
  }, function(error){ 
   // here you treat your error 
  }
);
```